# How to inspect a Groovy list recursively?

Tags: groovy

I was going to use Groovy's `inspect()` methods for quick and dirty object persistence but it didn't work as I expected. More specifically if I `inspect()` a list then list items are not `inspect()`ed but rather are `toString()`ed instead. Consider the following script:

```
class Foo {
    String inspect() { 'new Foo()' }
}

assert new Foo().inspect() == 'new Foo()'      // passes as expected
assert [new Foo()].inspect() == '[new Foo()]'  // fails
```

Running this script produces the following output:

```
Assertion failed:

assert [new Foo()].inspect() == '[new Foo()]'
        |          |         |
        |          |         false
        |          [Foo@3d52315f]
        Foo@3d52315f

        at test.run(test.groovy:6)
```

meaning that `inspect()` on my `Foo` instance is never called. Is this a Groovy bug? I'm testing with Groovy 2.4.1.

Comment: Not sure you should use this for any sort of persistence

Comment: Why would you do this instead of simple serialization? (If the goal is trivial persistence, I mean.)

Comment: and just to talk about the elephant in the room: how do you parse this back in? Eval?  be tripple times sure, that no one can interfere with the persisted data here or build a proper jail for evaluating in again. i'd rather go with any text representation (xml,json,edn,yaml,...) than opening this can of worms.

Comment: @DaveNewton how simple is 'simple serialization?' @cfrick Yes I planned to evaluate() it. It was adequate for a single-use, personal, offline script. In the end I used JsonBuilder/JsonSlurper but we're sidetracking. The question wasn't about how to serialize safely and properly. It was about why `inspect()` worked as it did.

Comment: @SnakE Pretty simple. Personally I think relying on a mechanism like `inspect` for serialization is really suspect, there are just too many variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way:

```
class Foo {
    String inspect() { 'new Foo()' }
}

assert new Foo().inspect() == 'new Foo()'      // passes as expected
assert [new Foo()]*.inspect().toString() == '[new Foo()]'
```

You need to call inspect on every element of the list provided and then make to list *inspectable* itself. But indeed the behavior seems strange when it comes to the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#inspect()).

It seems that this is a bug. From [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java) call to `inspect()` is redirected to [InvokerHelper](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.java). Since you pass a collection (list) `formatList` method will be invoked. This method iterates over the list passed and calls `format` in the same class. Since `format`doesn't know about `Foo` it will call `toString` to the object passed (line 629).

The following example shows how it works:

```
class Foo {
    String inspect() { 'new Foo()' }

    String toString() { 'new Foo()' }
}

assert new Foo().inspect() == 'new Foo()'     
assert [new Foo()].inspect() == '[new Foo()]'
```

Comment: While this works around the problem in the trivial single-list case it breaks if any kind of complexity is added, e.g. `[[new Foo()]]`

Comment: @SnakE is your question answered?

Comment: Well no. You just confirm my observations which I already knew were true. I expected an answer along the lines "`inspect()` works like this  by design, here's a proof link with rationale," or "yes this is a bug, here's a bug tracker link." I ended up filing a bug against the Groovy JDK. There will be the real answer when it is confirmed or declined.